# How to "pivot longer" and populate with fields from column names at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Sony | TV | Model | value': {0: 'A222', 1: 'A234', 2: 'A4345'}, 'Sony | TV | Quantity | value': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 4}, 'Sony | TV | Max-quant | value': {0: 10, 1: 9, 2: 9}, 'Panasonic | TV | Model | value': {0: 'T232', 1: 'S3424', 2: 'X3421'}, 'Panasonic | TV | Quantity | value': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 1}, 'Panasonic | TV | Max-quant | value': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 11}, 'Sanyo | Radio | Model | value': {0: 'S111', 1: 'S1s1', 2: 'S1s2'}, 'Sanyo | Radio | Quantity | value': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 4}, 'Sanyo | Radio | Max-quant | value': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 10}} )
```

Each column is made up of four fields: manufacturer, device, model and a value. I need to pivot the table into a longer format, but also parse information from the column names.
The output should look like this:

```
Manufacturer    Device  Model   Quantity    Max quantity
Sony              TV    A222       5            10
Sony              TV    A234       5            9
Sony              TV    A4345      4            9
Panasonic         TV    T232       1            10
Panasonic         TV    S3424      5            12
Panasonic         TV    X3421      1            11
Sanyo             Radio S111       4            9
Sanyo             Radio S1s1       2            9
Sanyo             Radio S1s2       4            10
```

In R I would have used pivot_longer along with names_pattern, and then pivot_wider.

How could this be done in Python ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696646/reshaping-a-table-in-r-while-parsing-information-from-column-names-and-using-it and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714874/how-to-pivot-wider-and-fill-in-missing-values-by-duplicating-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Sony | TV | Model | value': {0: 'A222', 1: 'A234', 2: 'A4345'}, 
                    'Sony | TV | Quantity | value': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 4}, 
                    'Sony | TV | Max-quant | value': {0: 10, 1: 9, 2: 9}, 
                    'Panasonic | TV | Model | value': {0: 'T232', 1: 'S3424', 2: 'X3421'}, 
                    'Panasonic | TV | Quantity | value': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 1}, 
                    'Panasonic | TV | Max-quant | value': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 11}, 
                    'Sanyo | Radio | Model | value': {0: 'S111', 1: 'S1s1', 2: 'S1s2'}, 
                    'Sanyo | Radio | Quantity | value': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 4}, 
                    'Sanyo | Radio | Max-quant | value': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 10}} )

# Create a multiIndex column header
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('\s?\|\s?')))

#Reshape the dataframe using `set_index`, `droplevel`, and `stack`
df.stack([0,1]).droplevel(1, axis=1).set_index('Model', append=True)\
               .rename_axis([None,'Manufacturer', 'Device', 'Model'])\
               .sort_index(level=[1,2,3])\
               .reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Manufacturer Device  Model  Max-quant  Quantity
0    Panasonic     TV  S3424       12.0       5.0
1    Panasonic     TV   T232       10.0       1.0
2    Panasonic     TV  X3421       11.0       1.0
3        Sanyo  Radio   S111        9.0       4.0
4        Sanyo  Radio   S1s1        9.0       2.0
5        Sanyo  Radio   S1s2       10.0       4.0
6         Sony     TV   A222       10.0       5.0
7         Sony     TV   A234        9.0       5.0
8         Sony     TV  A4345        9.0       4.0
```

Comment: I think we can fix that using + after  using \s+? after and before the | in the split.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) that could help in abstracting the reshaping from wide to long form:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ('Manufacturer', 'Device', '.value'), 
                names_pattern = r"(.+)\s\|(.+)\s\|(.+)\s\|.+")
 
  Manufacturer  Device  Model   Quantity   Max-quant
0         Sony      TV   A222          5          10
1         Sony      TV   A234          5           9
2         Sony      TV  A4345          4           9
3    Panasonic      TV   T232          1          10
4    Panasonic      TV  S3424          5          12
5    Panasonic      TV  X3421          1          11
6        Sanyo   Radio   S111          4           9
7        Sanyo   Radio   S1s1          2           9
8        Sanyo   Radio   S1s2          4          10
```